# Count how many times distinct values repeat in another column with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

so I got a column with hundreds of different first names and another column with 7 different neighborhoods that repeat multiple times.

I want to check what are the most common names for each neighborhood. How would I go about it?

Thanks and I hope I made my question clear enough.

I tried the below, and got this error - SQL Error: Syntax error: Encountered " "COUNT" "Count "" at line 8, column 5. Was expecting: EOF

```
SELECT 
host_name, neighbourhood_group,
    COUNT(*) AS Ct
FROM AB_NYC_2019
GROUP BY
    host_name,
    neighbourhood_group,
 Max Count AS
 (
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(Ct) OVER
    (
        PARTITION BY neighbourhood_group
    ) AS MaxCt
FROM Counts
)
SELECT
neighbourhood_group,
host_name
FROM MaxCounts
WHERE Ct = MaxCt;
```

Comment: Have you already tried something, maybe by using group by? If you show what you tried it will be easier to answer your question

Comment: Yeah sorry, just added what I tried

Comment: Usually now you would provide a few `Insert Into AB_NYC_2019 ....` test data sample rows and describe the result you would want to get From those given test data

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
(select host_name,neighbourhood_group, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY neighbourhood_group order by c desc) as RN  
from(select host_name,neighbourhood_group,count(*) as c 
from AB_NYC_2019 group by host_name,neighbourhood_group)m)n where 
RN=1;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I tried it, but I get an error - SQL Error: Syntax error: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 2, column 52.
Was expecting:
    ")" ...

Comment: Which database server are you using?The above query is for mysql 8.0.

Comment: Using 8.0, no idea why it's not working

Comment: I have added a demonstartion [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=35997181b431993f6448576aa64a7e2a) .Is this how you are also using this query?

Comment: Thanks again. Still getting the same syntax error. The part of the syntax with the error is I think - (PARTITION BY neighbourhood_group order by c desc) though I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: To make your answer complete, you could explain the steps.

Comment: Can you maybe just check your MySQL version once again.You can use `select version();`. RANK() function is only supported in MYSQL 8.0. If you use a lower version,this function may not be recognised.

Comment: Yeah it is 8.0.29